# i was making calculatorapp in python using kivy when i started configuring buttons i got an error and even the indentation is not the same as aspected

Tags: python, kivy, calculator

this is my calc.py

```
   from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (500,700)
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def clear (self):
        self.ids.calc_input.text = "0"

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().run()
```

this is my calc.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<WindowManager>:
    Screen1

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:4
            rows:5

            TextInput:
                id: clac_input
                text: "0"
                halign: "right"
                font_size : 65
                size_hint: (1, .15)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "%"

            Button:

                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "CE"


            Button:
                id: clear
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "C"
                on_press : root.clear()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "/"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "7"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "8"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "9"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "x"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "4"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "5"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "6"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "-"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "1"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "2"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "3"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+/-"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "0"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "."

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "="
```

this is the video from which i was making it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu-HP4eOYM4

and whenever i am pressing the button here c because that is only 1 programmed it closes the program and i get this error

```
 AttributeError: 'Screen1' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

and even the indentation i got is not same as shown in the video so please help me

please tell if extra information is needed

Comment: please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code:

- Typo in your `kv` file. Change `id: clac_input` to `id: calc_input`.
- The error message tells you that the `clear()` method is not in `Screen1`. In fact, you have defined that method in the `MyLayout` class. Just move the `clear()` method into `Screen1`:

  ```
   class Screen1(Screen):
       def clear (self):
           self.ids.calc_input.text = "0"
  ```
- Move the `TextInput` out of the `GridLayout` and into the `BoxLayout`:

  ```
   <Screen1>:
       BoxLayout:
           orientation:"vertical"
           size: root.width, root.height

           TextInput:
               id: calc_input
               text: "0"
               halign: "right"
               font_size : 65
               size_hint: (1, .15)

           GridLayout:
           .
           .
           .
  ```
- Naming your `App` as `App` is a bad idea as `App` is already defined by `Kivy` and your are redefining the class `App`. I suggest changing it to just about anything other than `App`.

Comment: ...
       4:
       5:
 >>    6:   <Screen1>:
       7:     BoxLayout:
       8:         orientation:"vertical"
 ...
 Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of 4 spaces                                                                                        and now i am getting this error please help to solve

Comment: Check your indentation. The `orientation:` line must be indented 4 space from the `BoxLayout:` line.